# Adding a sound to load with a spash screen in xcode

Tags: xcode, iphone-sdk-3.2, splash-screen

I have set up a splash screen for my app project and would like to have an sound (mp3)  play just after the splash screen loads.  I am new to using xcode and wondered whether some one could advise on what code I will need to input/where to input it..

Many Thanks

Comment: Sorry this is for an iPhone and I have used 'default.png' for the splash screen

Comment: & I meant 'Splash' Screen in the title - Oh my tired eyes :-)

Answer (score 0):

You implement a yourintrosound.wav system sound in the first view controller, then play it with the appDelegate just after the view controller is loaded:

*in your firstViewController.h*

```
@interface...

CFURLRef yourSound;
SystemSoundID   soundFileObject;

 @property (readwrite) CFURLRef yourSound;
 @property  SystemSoundID soundFileObject;
```

*in your firstViewController.m viewDidLoad*

```
NSURL *rightSound   = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource: @"yourintrosound" withExtension: @"wav"];
self.yourSound = (CFURLRef) [rightSound retain];
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID (yourSound, &soundFileObject);
[rightSound release];
```

*in your AppDelegate.m  application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:*

(just after [window makeKeyAndVisible] or any splash screen display you implemented)

```
 AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (firstViewController.soundFileObject);
```

and do dot forget the AudioToolbox framework!